# How to set intercept to 1 in logistic regression and extract specific values?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model

I'm trying to fit a logistic regression model to some data using glm() in R.

The data comes from something related to sound propagation, thus in the example I give:

x = distance

y = proportion of signal at that point

count = median count of signal

It took me a while to work out the best approach (I still don't know whether it's the best) but after reading around I came to the conclusion as the data in proportion form is bound between 0 and 1, and owing to dissipation with distance, the best way to model this might be using logistic regression.

Typically I understood logistic regression to have a response variable which was either 0 or 1 exactly. However, after reading this post I decided to use a similar method (http://sherrytowers.com/2018/03/07/logistic-binomial-regression/)

I have some outstanding issues however:

1. Is this a correct way to model this type of data?
2. Given that signal strength at x = 0 should be 100% (i.e. 1 on y axis) how can I force the model to do this (please show in code) (i.e. force intercept to 1 at distance 0).
3. the two horizontal lines are theoretically representative of points at which y = 0.5 and y = 0.05 (i.e. 50% of signal strength and 5% of signal strength) - how can I extract the x values for these (distance at which this occurs; please show in code)

Here is a repex describing the above:

```
# creating data 
df = data.frame(y = c(0.56,0.294,0.556,0.543, 0.02, 0.241, 0.01, 0.435, 0.329, 0.548),
                count = c(5.6522335,2.9427240,5.5612497,5.4321732 ,0.2384215,2.4116196,0.1077007,4.3548918,3.2932310,5.4793094),
                x = c(12,293,302,30,602,314,458,172,153,140))

# getting beta for the model
# 10 is the max signal that can be achieved in count
b = glm(cbind(count,10-count)~x,family = "quasibinomial", data = df)


# creates sequence of used to plot curve
newdata = data.frame(x = seq(1:1000))
# getting predictions from 0 to 1000 (this function is on the webpage above all it does is extract CIs)
ypred = get_prediction_and_confidence_intervals_from_binomial_fit(b,newdata)

# setting maximum y for graph
ymax = 1

# plotting model
ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y), data = df) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = newdata$x,y = ypred[,1])) +
  geom_line(aes(x = newdata$x,y = ypred[,2]), size = 2, colour = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(x = newdata$x,y = ypred[,3]), size = 2, colour = "red") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = .5) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = .05)
```

The other thing I don't quite understand is why the model requires a dataframe with two column to calculate proportion (i.e. cbind(count,10-count) in the function call? If I provide the response as proportion it won't work, why?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are doing. You describe three variables (`x`, `y`, `count`). A logistical regression would be one way of modeling a value between 0 and 1, which `y` appears to be. But then you model not `y`, but `count`, using a quasibinomial family (which would be quite appropriate for a count variable). Can you please clarify?

Comment: Well in the GLM call it uses cbind(count,10-count) which is essentially the value as a proportion from my understanding (pls see link provided). This was also strange to me. I'm guessing that the model itself changes it to proportion when it is specified in this manner (which is equal to y).

Comment: In R, read `?binomial` which explains that the response can be specified in one of three ways. To specify a model with some known coefficient value, use `offset ` . Search this site for offset.

Comment: I tried using offset by adding a column called intercept to the data and then specifying the following:

~~~glm(cbind(count,10-count)~-1 + I(x) + offset(intercept), family = "quasibinomial",data=df)~~~

However I couldn't get it to work. If you could show me using the example provided that would be great.